# Exception thrown in linked list

Tags: c

I need to write a function that returns the size of a linked list. It seems simple enough, but I get an exception when I try to advance my pointer.
This is the code:

```
int List_size(List *list)
{
    List_node *p;
    int counter = 0;
    p = list->head;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

This is the code that defines the linked list:

```
typedef struct List_node
{
    int data;
    struct List_node *next;
    struct List_node *prev;
}List_node;

typedef struct List
{
    List_node *head;
}List;
```

And this is the code that creates the list:

```
List *create_list(int n)
{
    List *list = (List*) calloc(n,sizeof(List));
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

Lastly, I have inserted data (numbers) into the list using these two functions: (so don't think the lists are empty).

```
void insert_first(List_node *x, List *list)
{
    x->next = list->head;
    list->head = x;
}

void insert(List_node *x, List_node *y)
{
    x->next = y->next;
    y->next = x;
}

List_node *mk_node(int data, int n) 
{
    List_node *node = (List_node *)calloc(n, sizeof(List_node));
    node->data = data;
    return node;
}
```

Using a breakpoint I discovered that the problem lies in p = p->next, but I don't understand why.

Thank you very much.

edit - I did not think the full code is necessary, but here it is:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "List.h"

void merge(List *small_list, List *big_list)
{
    List_node *x, *y;
    y = small_list->head;
    x = big_list->head;
    t = x->prev;

//  while (y < x) //If there are smaller numbers on the small list, insert them first
//  {
//      insert(y,t)
//      t = t->next;
//      y = y->next;
//  }

    while (y != NULL && x->next != NULL)
    {
        if (x <= y && x->next >= y)
        {
            insert(y, x);
            y = y->next;
        }
        else
            x = x->next;
    }
    while (y != NULL)
    {
        insert(y, x);
        y = y->next;
    }
}

void main()
{
    List *L1, *L2, *big_list, *small_list;
    int num1, num2;
    int i;
    int a, b;

    create_list(5,&L1);
    create_list(3,&L2);

    printf("Insert first number into L1\n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    node = mk_node(0,5);
    insert_first(node, &L1);
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++) 
    {
        printf("Now insert the rest of the numbers\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        next = mk_node(&num1,5);
        insert(next, node);
        node = next;
    }

    printf("Insert first number into L2\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    node = mk_node(0,3);
    insert_first(node, &L2);
    for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("Now insert the rest of the numbers\n");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        next = mk_node(&num2,3);
        insert(next, node);
        node = next;
    }

//If lists are in descending order, reverse them to ascending order
        //if (L1->head > L1->head->next)
   //       reverse(L1);
    //  if (L2->head > L2->head->next)
        //  reverse(L2);

    int size_L1 = List_size(L1);
    int size_L2 = List_size(L2);

    if (size_L1 <= size_L2)
    {
        big_list = L2;
        small_list = L1;
    }
    else
    {
        big_list = L1;
        small_list = L2;
    }

    merge(small_list, big_list);

    print_list(L3);
    getchar(); getchar();
}
```

As you can see, I inserted the numbers using the function insert(). I hope it is okay.

The function reverse is: (I really hope it works, I translated it from pseudo-code)

```
List reverse(List *list)
{
    List_node *x, *y, *z;
    if (list->head == NULL || list->head->next == NULL)
    {
        return *list;
    }
    x = list->head;
    y = list->head->next;
    z = list->head->next->next;
    x->next = NULL;
    while (z != NULL)
    {
        y->next = x;
        x = y;
        y = z;
        z = z->next;
    }
    y->next = x;
    list->head = y;
}
```

Basically, this is an assignment that says I have two 2-directional **sorted** linked lists, and I'm supposed to merge them into one big sorted linked list.

As for the exception - Unhandled exception at 0x00E21766 in Lists.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD0.

Edit - the print_list function:

```
void print_list(List *list)
{
    List_node *p;
    p = list->head;
    printf("The linked list consists of: ");
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Seems you are not setting `x->next = NULL` as it need to be set to NULL so that list end up at some point. Take a look to [LinkedListBasics](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf) for reference.

Comment: How exactly did you insert values in the list ?

Comment: "An exception" - it might be helpful if you state which one.

Comment: I copied the above code into my compiler. This code doesn't compile, so it won't run. it is useless to give create_list a parameter. Same for mk_node. They will allocate an array, not create a list element. A call of calloc(1, sizeof(your_thing)) would suffice. The calls to create_list don't compile: they return a value as function return, not in a paameter. There are undeclared variables. As this code won't compile, it won't run. So I can't help you. Please compile your code and then post the code that compiles and runs.

Comment: I would never have posted my code here if it didn't compile (if I did I would definitely note that), so I have no idea why it didn't work for you. I saw your suggestions and the code you made for the merge function, thank you very much for that, I will try it and update you. I do wonder why my function doesn't work. The idea is that you merge the two lists into the big list, and it worked great when I checked it on paper (pseudo-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a comment above that I copied your code into my compiler and that it doesn't compile, so it won't run: the calls to create_list don't compile: they return a value as function return, not in a parameter; there are undeclared variables.  Further, it is useless to give create_list and mk_node a parameter: they will allocate an array, not create a single list element. A call of calloc(1, sizeof(your_thing)) would suffice. After fixing these erors, several bugs became apparent:

- in insert_first(node, &L2); you give it the address of the list, which is already a pointer. Remove the '&' (the compiler should have complained!).
- same for List_size(&L1); L1 is already a pointer. Remove the '&'.
- in: if (x <= y ...) you compare memory addresses. Change to: if (x->data <= y->data...)
- in that statement the part "x->next >= y" also compares memory address, and I don't see why it is needed. I removed it.

The real problem seems to be in merge. You should either merge the lists into L1, or into L2, and preferably should create a result list. But you "randomly" insert an element into L1, then into L2, then again into L1, etcetera. In my test it ran indefinitly. The following merge works fine:

```
List *merge(List *small_list, List *big_list)
{
    List_node *x, *y, *r;
    List *result= create_list();
    y = small_list->head;
    x = big_list->head;

    if (x->data < y->data)
         {result->head= x; x= x->next;}
    else {result->head= y; y= y->next;}
    r= result->head;

    while (y != NULL && x != NULL)
    {
        if (x->data < y->data)
        {
            r->next= x;
            x = x->next;
        }
        else {
            r->next= y;
            y = y->next;
        }
        r= r->next;
    }
    while (y != NULL)
    {
        r->next= y;
        y = y->next;
        r= r->next;
    }
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        r->next= x;
        x = x->next;
        r= r->next;
    }
    r->next= 0;
    return (result);
}
```

Comment: Alright, so I looked at your notes and used your function, but now I want to print the list, and I can't seem to do it. The numbers I print are weird numbers (memory addresses?). I posted a function called `print_list`, can you take a look at it? Thank you.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. Just wanted to say thank you again, everything works now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in code you did not show, because all the code you give is fine (*).

I could use your structs and functions to :

- create a List
- add a first node (with insert_first)
- add other nodes (with insert)
- get the size (using List_size)
- display the data value of every node
- free the nodes and the list

Here's the full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct List_node
{
    int data;
    struct List_node *next;
    struct List_node *prev;
}List_node;

typedef struct List
{
    List_node *head;
}List;

List *create_list()
{
    List *list = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}

int List_size(List *list)
{
    List_node *p;
    int counter = 0;
    p = list->head;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    return counter;
}

void insert_first(List_node *x, List *list)
{
    x->next = list->head;
    list->head = x;
}

void insert(List_node *x, List_node *y)
{
    x->next = y->next;
    y->next = x;
}

/* my own additions */
List_node *mk_node(int data) {
    List_node *node = (List_node *) malloc(sizeof(List_node));
    node->data = data;
    return node;
}

void delete_list(List *list) {
    List_node *node = list->head;
    while (node != NULL) {
        List_node *next = node ->next;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
    free(list);
}

int main() {
    List* list = create_list();
    List_node *node, *next;
    int i;

    node = mk_node(0);
    insert_first(node, list);
    for (i=1; i<5; i++) {
        next = mk_node(i);
        insert(next, node);
        node = next;
    }

    int n = List_size(list);
    printf("size : %d\n", n);

    node = list->head;
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("node val : %d\n", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    delete_list(list);
    return 0;
}
```

(*) Your code is not perfect because `List_node` struct contains a pointer `prev` that is never used, so you end with a single-linked list with every third value unused.

Comment: The *prev* is to be used later (I did not include it in the code yet but I will).

Comment: @Eran I supposed it was something like that ... so your code is fine what what you show !

Comment: Just to make sure - you insert in *node* and *next* after that numbers between 0 (to node) and 4 (to next)? I assume you're giving *node* the number 0 just so it will be overriden later, and to *next* I should give the numbers I get from the user?

Comment: Also one more question... I will now add a few lines into the *merge* function, lines which will insert the number *y* into *x->prev*. Can you show me how I can implement that? (I assume I will have to write another function like *insert*?) Will it be just like the *insert* function, only I will replace the next with prev? (or something similiar)

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that you allocate the list head, but never allocate memory for the list elements. Serge added mk_node which does the allocation (so Serge solved it).

Comment: Well, the loop is somewhat working, but is throwing another exception when the counter reaches 5 (which is the size of the list): `Unhandled exception at 0x003817F0 in Lists.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD0.` I tried changing what is inside of the while loop to `while (p->next != NULL) but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Use calloc in stead of malloc. calloc zeroes the memory; malloc does not. So if you test for zero, you won't see zero because the memory hasn't been zeroed. The value 0xCCCCetc is typical of a compiler in debug mode that intentionally sets the memory to this value so your program gets this error so you know you forgot to zero it. (I use MS VC 2005, which does this)

Comment: I can't use calloc - it shows an error `Error 1 error C2660: 'calloc' : function does not take 1 arguments`. 
I'll post the new code based on what Serge showed.

Comment: By the way, the if's before the reverse function don't work as well. `Unhandled exception at 0x00291B18 in Lists.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.` It shows the *head* is NULL, but isn't it supposed to be filled with data after I inserted the numbers?

Comment: Dear @Eran, if your compiler warns about the calloc arguments then lookup the calloc definition. "I can't use calloc" sounds a bit silly. Further, "the if's don't work": sure they don't work: if (x<=y) where x and y are memory adresses will never work because you want to know if the list elements are smaller, not whether their memory addresses are smaller...

Comment: You're right, I did that, and used calloc, but it still doesn't work. I'll leave the reverse function for now because I want to understand why the loop is not working, even though I used the calloc function. As I said, it reaches 5 (size of list L1), but when getting the to line `p->next` it breaks. The *locals* window below shows that all fields of `p` (head, data and prev) are ??? so I assume that is the reason it can't go to next. The question is, how do I solve it? I posted any changes I made in the code.